# httpErrors not working in IIS Express 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express, iis-8

I've been trying to implement `httpErrors` for my website.

This is how it looks in my `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="500" path="Error/InternalServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

The paths are pointing to two Actions in an Error Controller.

I've tried changing `existingResponse` to `Replace`, `PassThrough` and  `Auto`. `errorMode` to `Detailed` and `Custom`. I also tried setting `defaultResponseMode` to `ExecuteURL`. They all return the default 404 error page or an empty white page.

I've tried looking in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` since a few other thread suggested it, but it's empty.

I'm using IIS Express v8.0.8418.0 on Windows 8.1